# Finding 1882-83 Immigration Record through Castle Garden

Tags: immigration, new-york-city, 1880s

I have searched for my great Grandmother Catherine Schneider in the lists of immigrants coming through Castle Garden.  She came over in 1882-1883.  I have not been able to find her.

Does anyone have suggestions on where she might be?

She came from Bretzenheim near Mainz in Germany.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH,SE! Your question is not likely to attract good answers because you haven't shown your research effort.  Your question could be improved by telling us why you think she arrived in 1882-1883, where you have searched the Castle Garden-era passenger lists, and what search methods you used.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the spelling of her first name. It might as well have been spelled "Katharina" or "Catharina" as this is the German variant of that name. I see at least two Katharina/Catharina Schneider arriving approx. at that time in the USA in the [United States Germans to America Index, 1850-1897](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/2110801) database of FamilySearch (registration required). To be sure you will have to know her (approximate) birth year.